# add multiples to a php switch case

Tags: php, loops, templates, layout

Super new to PHP and looked for duplicates but I might be searching for the wrong terminology

I have this query to load a different post template when running the query so I can load a more interesting page layout for a blog homepage

```
<?php 
    $query_args = array(
        'post_type'=> 'post', 'feature', 'fashion', 'film',
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'cat' => -13
          );

      $query = new WP_query ($query_args);
      if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                  $count = (0);
      }
?>

<section class="blog-posts grid">

<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

  if ( get_post_type()) {
      switch($count) {
          case 0: include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of2.php' )); break; 
          case 1: include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of2.php' )); break;
          case 2: include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of1.php' )); break;
          case 3: include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of3.php' )); break;
          case 4: include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of3.php' )); break;
          case 5: include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of3.php' )); break;   
          default: include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of1.php' ));
      }
      $count++;
  }

    endwhile; ?>

    <div class="load-more">
        <button>Load More</button>
    </div>

</section>
```

Is it possible to add an nth-child situation to the cases so that each renders itself on the correct multiple?

so case 0 would be 0n+1 so that I can load all of my posts into this structure?

I am trying to achieve this layout

[image]

(that carries on duplicating with a load more (later))

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: `$count = (0);` ???

Comment: What does that mean ? @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course man! There are really simple solutions for Your situation

> You need to use "%" arithmetic operator called "Module"
>
> $a % $b = Remainder of $a divided by $b

### How module works

```
/** 
 * Example of % operator works
 * 0 % 4 = 0 START
 * 1 % 4 = 1
 * 2 % 4 = 2
 * 3 % 4 = 3
 * 4 % 4 = 0 (RE)START
 * 5 % 4 = 1
 * 6 % 4 = 2
 * 7 % 4 = 3
 * 8 % 4 = 0 (RE)START
 * ...
 */
```

## Sol. 1 : Using multiple cases + Module operator

```
while(...) :

/** 
 * Example. In your case $totalStylesNumber = 5 
 */
$templateIndex = $count % $totalStylesNumber;

switch($templateIndex) {
    case 0 : case 1:
        include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of2.php' )); 
        break;
    case 3: case 4: case 5:
        include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of3.php' )); 
        break;
    default: /** include case 2 */
        include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of1.php' )); 
        break;
}

$count++;

endwhile;
```

## Sol.2 : Using if sentences + Module operator

```
while(...) :

/** 
 * Example. In your case $totalStylesNumber = 5 
 */
$templateIndex = $count % $totalStylesNumber;

/** case 3, case 4, case 5 */
if($templateIndex > 2)
    include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of3.php' ));
/** case 0, case 1 */
else if($templateIndex > -1 && $templateIndex != 2)
    include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of2.php' ));
/** default */
else
    include( locate_template( 'includes/homepage-1of1.php' )); 

$count++;

endwhile;
```

Comment: Hey ! How does this help me duplicate my original loop for say posts 7-12, 13-18 and so on so forth? This just appears to be a really good way of shortening the query ?

Comment: Because "style" of posts is looping. You can divide $count for styles number. Example $count = 12, if styles are 4, You have 3 loop of same templates

Comment: you are the man ! All I needed to do was define the totalstylenumber and it works, like an absolute charm - thank you so much for taking the time to explain and write such an excellent response. I owe you !